# Where do I find robo dogs?

Tags: achievements, far-cry-3-blood-dragon

Where can I find robo dogs in *Far Cry 3: Blood Dragon*? This is the last animal I need for  the "Murder Nature" achievement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will encounter robo-dogs or cyber-dogs in the missions, [Punch It](http://www.ign.com/wikis/far-cry-3-blood-dragon/Punch_It), [What is this S4!t?](http://www.ign.com/wikis/far-cry-3-blood-dragon/What_is_this_S4!t%3F) and [I Don't Deal With Psychos, I Put 'Em Away](http://www.ign.com/wikis/far-cry-3-blood-dragon/I_Don't_Deal_With_Psychos,_I_Put_'Em_Away) (third, fourth and fifth missions, respectively).

Also, some outposts or garrisons have them. Try attacking outposts too.

Comment: Do you know which garrisons?

Comment: @CyberSkull I can't recall at the moment, I'm afraid. The missions are a sure way to encounter robo-dogs.

Comment: This lines up with [my experiences](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/far-cry-3-blood-dragon-achievement-guide/) as well.  I also can't recall a specific garrison that had them, although I'm fairly sure there was at least one with one...